# Disable directive based on dropdown value

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to disable the multiselect dropdown directive based on the selection of the other drop down.
This is the 1st drop down

```
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                <label for="labelState">State</label>
                                <select id="zone" class="form-control btn btn-default"
                                        ng-disabled="!states"
                                        ng-model="currentState"
                                        ng-options="state as state for state in states"></select>
                            </div>
```

This is the multi select drop down.

```
              `<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                                <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
                                    <label for="ratingState">State</label>
                                    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
                                         ng-disabled="currentState === 'Select State'"
                                         options="example14data"
                                         selected-model="example14model"
                                         checkboxes="true"
                                         extra-settings="example14settings">
                                    </div>                                       
                                </div>
                            </div>`
```

When i try to disable simple button based on 1st drop down selection it is working fine but the same thing is not working with the multi select drop down directive.

```
                                  <input type="button" 
                                   ng-disabled="currentState === 'Select State'"                                      
                                   class="btn btn-primary btn-md" />
```

Answer (score 0):

With [angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect), to disable a dropwdown you must use disabled and not ng-disabled.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <label for="ratingState">State</label>
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
         disabled="currentState === 'Select State'"
         options="example14data"
         selected-model="example14model"
         checkboxes="true"
         extra-settings="example14settings">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure ? Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jtassin/8gue5e1p/2/